# How can I free up unused disk space without root access?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, quota

I am trying to learn quota on linux systems. I have low privileged access to an ubuntu machine via ssh. I am supposed to create a 14 MB file on the machine where quota is set to 20MB. However around 7 MB is already used up and I cannot find where these files are.

1. How can I clean up some space from this?
2. Is there a way to figure out what is using up this 7.5 MB space?

How can I free up the above 7.5 MB file?

Comment: Generally, you need to delete something to free space, and if you do not know what's there, look for it with `ls`.

Comment: @mikewhatever The reason of this post is that the content of my home folder didn't add up to 7 MB. I used `ls -al` to list down the files and folders. Let me know if there is any way to clear cache, buffer etc. I have tried all the methods mentioned in the forums. Most of them require a high privilege level.

Comment: What caches and buffers, etc? What makes you think there are any?

Comment: because I cannot find any files using up the space in my home or sub directories. Enlighten me any other places which would affect my disk quotas.

Comment: So, to recap, you want me to find the used space without access to the system, and without you posting any meaningful outputs. How am I supposed to do that? May be magic, abracadabra!.

Comment: Pardon if I was unclear. 

This is the quota

`Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/vdb1    7852   10240   20480              11    4096    8192`

I am unsure what is using up 7852 blocks of my memory.

I searched in my home directory and sub directories and the usage is not more than 1 MB. I am trying hard to understand whether there would be hidden files in Ubuntu which cannot be seen by `ls -al` which might be affecting my quota.

Comment: @hax [edit] your question to provide that info, don't put it into a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your inputs. The space was being used up by a link to a process which was deleted. I was able to clear the space by killing the process.

```
lsof | grep -i deleted

kill -9 <pid>
```

Answer (score 2):

If installed on your distribution, you can use `baobab` to explore the files. Start it from the terminal and a nice GUI appears with information of your file system. You can also browse your file system to identify what files you want to delete.

Other tools you can try if installed:

```
filelight
gdmap
k4dirstat
jdiskreport
```

Or also `du -shx ./* | sort -h`

Comment: Nice. But why does that not show my data partition when looking at `/`? Regarding the edit: he does not have an admin account (and just a limited ssh) so I doubt he can install it. Probably also is a server version so installing it will pull in a desktop ;)

Comment: Don't look at "/", look at your "Home folder".

Comment: My home is empty ;) All my personal dirs are on /discworld/ (Desktop is /discworld/Desktop for instance) but /discworld is not shown in baobab :P weird. AH `baobab /discworld`  works \o/

Comment: I cannot install anything as I am a low privileged user. sudo is also not available.

Comment: @hax: and what happens when you issue `baobab` in your terminal?

Comment: @RichArt `Command not found.` Since I am a low privileged user, I cannot install it either.

Comment: @hax: see my new edit above.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I clean up some space from this

- Delete something you can delete with `rm`.
- Or use `scp` to copy files over to your system, them `rm` them and put them back onto the system when done.
- Empty trash if applicable (server does not have a trash)

> Is there a way to figure out what is using up this space?

- `du -h` will list every directory with filesize from where you are at the time.